# Numbers not of length 5

Tags: regex

I want to find potential US zip codes which are a string of 5 numbers, such as `12345` or `90210`. The current regex I have uses alternation to get numbers of length 1-4 and then numbers of length 6+. Is there a better way to do this -- getting numbers of "all lengths except 5"?

- [`^(?:[0-9]{0,4}|[0-9]{6,})$`](https://regex101.com/r/Gxa4WQ/1) (regex 101)

Comment: `^(?!\d{5}$)\d+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!\d{5}$)\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7mFlw/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!%5Cd%7B5%7D%24)%5Cd%2B%24):

[image]

**Regex details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d{5}$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any five digits immediately to the right of the current location till the end of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

If the numbers are to be matched in a longer text as separate matches, you may consider using word, or digit, or even whitespace boundaries:

```js
\b(?!\d{5}\b)\d+            // word boundaries
(?<!\d)(?!\d{5}(?!\d))\d+   // digit boundaries
(?<!\S)(?!\d{5}(?!\S))\d+   // whitespace boundaries
```